# retrieving a document by id is slow across partitions in cosmos db

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a scenario where I need to retrieve a single document based on its id property from azure cosmos db. The only problem is I don't know the partition key and thus cannot use the document URI to access it.

From my understanding writing a simple query like

```
SELECT * from c WHERE c.id = "id here"
```

should be the way to go but I'm experiencing severe performance issues with this query. Most queries take 30s to 60s to complete and seem to consume insane amounts of RU/s. When executing 10 concurrent queries the max RU/s per partition went as high as 30.000. (10.00 per partition was provisioned) Resulting in throttling and even slower responses.

The collection comprises 10 partitions with around 3 Mb per partition, so 30 Mb in total and around 1,00,000 documents. My indexing policy looks like this:

```
{
    "indexingMode": "lazy",
    "automatic": true,
    "includedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/*",
            "indexes": [
                {
                    "kind": "Range",
                    "dataType": "Number",
                    "precision": -1
                },
                {
                    "kind": "Hash",
                    "dataType": "String",
                    "precision": 3
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "excludedPaths": []
}
```

And the consistency is set to `EVENTUAL` since I don't really care about read/write order. The collection is under some write pressure with about 30 writes per minute and there's a TTL of 1 year for each document, yet this doesn't seem to produce a measurable impact on the RU/s. I experience this sort of problem only when querying documents.

Has anyone had similar problems and can offer a fix/mitigation? Am I doing something wrong with my query or indexing policy? I don't know why my query is consuming that much resources.

Comment: I've experienced the same problem, but have no write pressure at all. Querying by any other indexed field is actually faster than querying by id.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My test DB about 300k record
When i try to select with ID only like this

```
SELECT * FROM c where c.id = 'xxx'
```

It take me alot of time and RU

But when i try with partition key in that

```
SELECT * FROM c where c.id = 'xxx' AND c.partitionField = 'yyy'
```

It's very fast

So I think you must recontruct your db, and thinking which field to make a partition

Comment: I didn't realise the issue was still open. I accepted your answer because I also found that one can only efficiently query by id if a partition key is specified. Although the reason for it is still imcomprehensible to me, I just came to accept the fact :D

Comment: The partitions are how the database is subdivided. So when you don't specifiy the partition key, it runs that query against each partition, leading to high RU's.

Answer (score 7):

I got similar problem even. My database is 16 GB with 2 partitions and has 10,000 RU per partition.

By gathering query metrics, I found that `query by id` could be doing table scan and not looking up from index.

Here is the metrics of query by id:

```
SELECT * FROM c where c.id = 'id-here'
--Read 1 record in 1497.00 ms, 339173.109 RU
--QueryPreparationTime(ms): CompileTime = 2, LogicalBuildTime = 0, 
     PhysicalPlanBuildTime = 0, OptimizationTime = 0
--QueryEngineTime(ms): DocumentLoadTime = 1126, IndexLookupTime = 0, 
     RuntimeExecutionTimes = 356, WriteOutputTime = 0
```

Notice the time spent mostly in `DocumentLoadTime` and `IndexLookupTime = 0`.

While query by indexed field is pretty fast.

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.indexedField = 'value'
--Read 4 records in 2.00 ms, 7.56 RU
--QueryPreparationTime(ms): CompileTime = 0, LogicalBuildTime = 0, 
       PhysicalPlanBuildTime = 0, OptimizationTime = 0
--QueryEngineTime(ms): DocumentLoadTime = 0, IndexLookupTime = 1, 
       RuntimeExecutionTimes = 0, WriteOutputTime = 0
```

Contrast to the query by id, this doesn't consumed `DocumentLoadTime` as the index was used, `IndexLookupTime` is 1 ms.

The problem is `id` should be the primary key and should be indexed by default but it looks like it doesn't. You couldn't even add custom indexing policy for it.

I'm currently logged a ticket to Microsoft support and waiting for clarifications.

**Update:**

Microsoft support responded and they've resolved the issue. They've added `IndexVersion 2` for the collection. Unfortunately, it is not yet available from the portal and newly created accounts/collection are still not using the new version. You'll have to contact Microsoft Support to made changes to your accounts.

Here are the new results from a collection with index version 2 and there's a massive improvement.

```
SELECT * FROM c where c.id = 'uniqueValue'
-- Index Version 1: Request Charge: 344,940.79 RUs
-- Index Version 2: Request Charge: 3.31 RUs

SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.indexedField = 'value' AND c.id = 'uniqueValue'
-- Index Version 1: Request Charge: 150,666.22 RUs 
-- Index Version 2: Request Charge: 5.65 RUs
```

Comment: Any news on this?

Comment: @MarkTrinidad any update on IndexVersion2 using portal or code?

Answer (score 1):

The key to Cosmos is to **Rethink the Partition Key**.
I don't know what you are using, but make it very available.

Recently I have been adding a 'Table' property to all of my documents, but you could very easily use the Table name as the Partition Key!  It's really almost like having a bunch SQL tables just kind of floating around in the pudding that is a CosmosDB collection.

Comment: In addition, if other people won't allow you to do that, one thing to consider is using an in-memory cache to store the key. It's cheap and extremely fast, and will save you a ton of time and money on RUs.

Comment: This was actually highlighted at Microsoft's Ignite Conference by Deborah Chen:
https://myignite.techcommunity.microsoft.com/sessions/65927?source=sessions
Check it out!

Comment: @A.Rowan  Hi, the link does not work. Please, could you update your comment. Many thanks.

Comment: @Sau001  Sorry, MS has taken down video from Ignite 2018.

Comment: @A.Rowan Thanks for looking into it. This could have been a very source of guidance in a increasingly confusing landscape.

Comment: Update for 2020, here's the new link to Deborah's video on choosing the right Cosmos DB Partition Key.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oqk41KY6rhA&feature=emb_logo